# Rejecting all cookies don't do anything

Tags: cookies, one-trust

I added OneTrust cookies consent modal/popup to my page
The thing is that when we click on "Reject all cookies" button, visitor's cookies are not being deleted, they are still there, if he reloads the page all cookies are still present, cookies from google analytics, from hotjar, etc, they dont get deleted!

I dont understand what is the purpose of rejecting all cookies when cookies are not being deleted??

Answer (score 0):

one trust does not block anything, is exposed a categories of cookies, based on that categories you need to create custom rules that block those scripts
in google tag manager, here the problem is google tag manager that inserting those offending scripts

see this video: https://community.cookiepro.com/s/article/Cookie-Blocking-Blocking-cookies-via-Tag-Managers-and-HTML?language=en_US